# mysql get a middle string and build on it

Tags: mysql

Let us say that I have this table

```
-----------------
|  id   |   word |
|  5    |   aab  |
|  6    |   sea  |
|  7    |   blue |
|  8    | color  |
|  9    |  nn    |
|  10   |  pp    |
|  11   |  oo    |
|  12   |  qq    |
```

a person visited the page where the `id` is `8`

what I want to display is two results before and after this `id`. those two results are alphabetically ordered so in the command I should get :

```
aab - blue - color - nn - oo
```

How can I do that in mysql query? I am looking for the best efficient code. How many querys do I need to run? How can I get the results before my id alphabitically and get only two from each side. Please help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, we're here to help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Why is `aab` and `oo` included, that is not `id=8` `-2` and `+2` is it `+/-3`?

Comment: alphabtical order.. before getting the two results.. that is why I asked the question

Comment: I found a very good example .. if you look at the left of the website : http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=close%20enough%20for%20government%20work&defid=1464981 you will see that there are results before the word and after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `limit` and `union all`:

```
select word
from ((select *
       from t
       where word<= (select word from t where id = 8)
       order by word desc
       limit 3
      ) union all
      (select *
       from t
       where word> (select word from t where id = 8)
       order by word
       limit 2
      )
     ) t
order by word;
```

Comment: I am not ordering by `id `.. I want it to be ordered alphabtically by `word`

Comment: @shnisaka . . . I got that.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: I thought the two columns were `word` and `id` :)

Comment: They are, but just change "name" to "word", and the answer is correct. Upvoting.

Comment: @meewoK . . . Oops, I totally missed the column names at the top.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Nice solution!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks so much, it worked just as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a sorted version of that table. Then, when given an ID, you can just do arithmetic on the IDs.

```
/* How to create the sorted table */
create table sorted_words 
(new_id mediumint not null auto_increment, primary key (new_id))
as select id as old_id, word from words order by word asc;

/* Query for getting two above and two under */
select id, word from sorted where id between 6 and 10
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6734/1